# Почему с помощью первого фрагмента можно изменить объект, объявленный с помощью const, а с помощью второго нет?

Tags: javascript, объекты

```js
**Первый фрагмент**

const user = {
  name: "John"
};

// сработает без проблем.
user.name = "Pete";


**Второй фрагмент**

const user = {
  name: "John"
};

// Ошибка (нельзя переопределять константу user)
user = {
  name: "Pete"
};
```

Хотя **user.name = "Pete";** и **user = {
  name: "Pete"
};** оба меняют значение свойства. Почему так? Я правильно думаю, что первый фрагмент работает правильно, так как в нем неявно меняется значение свойства, то есть по ссылке меняется. А во втором фрагменте явно меняется, то есть прямо в самом объекте пытается менять значение свойства и поэтому выдает ошибку. Так или нет? Если нет, то почему оно так работает?

Comment: Вынуть из коробки носки и положить туда ботинки - запросто. А вот переделать её в ящик с ботинками затруднительно...

Comment: в первом меняеться пропертя обьекта (сам обьект не меняеться), во втором меняеться сам обьект, но первый комент мне нравиться больше )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разжую комментарий @Akina:

> Вынуть из коробки носки и положить туда ботинки - запросто. А вот
>   переделать её в ящик с ботинками затруднительно

`const` работает не так, как может показаться. Если вы думаете, что создав переменную через `const` вы полностью сделаете ее неизменяемой, то это не так.

Если говорить просто, то любая переменная хранится в какой-то ячейке памяти. Так вот, `const` говорит, что положив что-то в ячейку памяти, мы уже не сможем поменять это значение.

Поэтому во втором случае у вас появляется ошибка, так как вы пытаетесь **положить в ячейку новое значение**. 
В первом же случае, ошибки нет, так как **значение в ячейке не меняется**, меняется св-во этого значение, которое лежит в другом месте ( и св-ва объекта это уже не `const` )